# How do I check if an Arraylist contains an Object?

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

I know I can check if an Arraylist al contains an specific String with e.g. "al.contains("Garage")".

But in my case, I have an Object I created. Do you have any solution? It just wont work.

```
if(User.users.contains(new User(userTextField.getText().toString(), 
passwordPasswordField.getPassword().toString()))) {
   System.out.println();
}
```

I create new Users like this

```
    User.users.add(new User("Franz", "1234"));
    User.users.add(new User("Heiko", "thePassoword"));
    User.users.add(new User("Christian", "test"));
    User.users.add(new User("Torsten", "pswdpswd"));
```

This is my User class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class User {

   public static ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

   private String name;
   private String password;

   public User(String name, String password) {
      this.name = name;
      this.password = password;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getPassword() {
      return password;
   }
   public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
   }

}
```

Comment: Since your list is not a list of strings, `contains("Garage")` won't work. You have to iterate the list yourself if you want to find a user with that name.

Answer (score 0):

The `contains()` method uses your classes implementation of `equals()` which extends from `Object`. To compare two `Users`, you should define an `equals()` method based on the parameters that you want to be checked.